# Diseño responsivo

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, responsive

yo hago paginas web con código. Y una persona me pidió una web y se la hice tanto la versión de escritorio como la de dispositivos móviles.

Pero el problema viene aquí. Mis dispositivos son windows y android, pero resulta que es IOS no se visualiza correctamente la web. No tengo dispositivos de apple, así que no puedo testearlos. Pero qué puede ser para que no se vea en IOS.

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Con que navegador visualiza mal la pagina web

Comment: Hay muchísimas diferencias entre navegadores. Chrome (chromium), Firefox, Opera, Safari, etc... Todos tienen distintas implementaciones de los standares web. Si dices que no se ve bien en iOS es posible que hayas utilizado alguna propedad de CSS que no está implementada por Webkit, que es el motor que utiliza Safari.

Comment: Si buscas en Google "herramientas para testear página web en diferentes dispositivos" o al go a´si vas a encontrar diferentes páginas que te permiten ver tu sitio en otros entornos. No es perfecto pero es bastante útil.